# Google App Engine Blank page localhost:8080

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am getting a blank page in "localhost:8080".

Followed the process mentioned in developers.google.com/appengine  for python

Everything is working fine but the webpage is not displaying "hello world" as mentioned in the helloworld.py file.

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

and app.yaml file is

```
application: engineapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
static_files: favicon.ico
upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Comment: Can you show us your actual code, please? Include the `app.yaml` file as well.

Comment: Does your console show any errors in the log?

Comment: And is your indentation correct?

Comment: I am using notepad++ for both files ... any problem with that ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if your main file is named `helloworld.py` then you will have to change the line `main.app` to `helloworld.app` or change your filename to match the first part.

Also as Martijn already mentioned your indentation should be correct in order to see the `Hello World!` and in what you posted in your question is totally not.

Here is the corrected ones

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
  ], debug=True)
```

and the *app.yaml*:

```
application: engineapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```